# How to make specific selectinputs blank after making changes to previous selectinputs ? (not based on the same data frame)

Tags: r, shiny

My shiny app uses two data frames. 
Manufacturer to £/mile select inputs uses one data frame called Data2. And the rest of the select inputs uses a different data frame called Distance.

If someone runs through the whole app, but then decides to change the model year, how do I get the origin/destination/distance in miles to go back to blank? 
(or just any changes to the selectinputs before origin without having to refresh the whole page)

I know that if I just keep to using one table, this can solve it but this means my data frame will become large,and i like the simplicity of using two dataframes for this. Any other way to do this?

Sorry if this q has been asked before, couldnt seem to find something like this anywhere!

Code:

```
library(shiny)
Data2 <- data.frame(Manufacturer= c(rep("ford", 4)), 
                     Model= c(rep("esport",2), rep("fiesta",2)),
                     Model_year5=c(2018, 2019, 2018, 2019), Fuel_type=c("petrol", "petrol", "diesel", "petrol" ), cost=c(2,4,6,8)
                     )

    Distance <- data.frame(Origin= c("leeds", "London", "Glasgow", "London", "Glasgow"), 
                            Destination = c("Bristol", "Cardiff", "London", "Leeds", "Bristol"),
                            Distance= c(12,13,14,15,16))


    ui <- fluidPage(
               tags$head(
                 tags$style(
                   HTML(
                     "        #div_id .selectize-control.single .selectize-input:after{
              content: none;
            }"
                   ),
                   "
                      #container * {  
       display: inline;
                         }")
               ),

               fluidRow(
                 column(4, wellPanel(
                   selectizeInput("Select1", "Choose Manufacturer", sort(Data2$Manufacturer), 
                                  options= list(
                                    placeholder = '',
                                    onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
                   selectizeInput("Select2", "Choose Model", sort(Data2$Model), 
                                  options= list(
                                    placeholder = '',
                                    onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
                   selectizeInput("Select3", "Choose Model Year", sort(Data2$Model_year5),
                                  options= list(
                                    placeholder = '',
                                    onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
                   selectizeInput("Select4", "Choose Fuel type", sort(Data2$Fuel_type),
                                  options= list(
                                    placeholder = '',
                                    onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
                   tags$div(id= "div_id",
                            selectInput("Select5", "£/mile", choices= NULL)),
                   selectizeInput("Select6", "Choose Origin", sort(Distances$Origin),
                                  options= list(
                                    placeholder = '',
                                    onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
                   selectizeInput("Select7", "Choose Destination", sort(Distances$Distance),
                                  options= list(
                                    placeholder = '',
                                    onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
                   tags$div(id= "div_id",
                            selectInput("Select8", "Distance in Miles", choices= NULL)),
                   div(id="container", strong('Total cost of journey: £'), textOutput("total1"))

                 ))))

    server <- function(input, output,session) {
      output$table = renderTable({
        costtable
      })
      observeEvent(input$Select1,{
        updateSelectizeInput(session,'Select2',
                             choices=unique(Data2$Model[Data2$Manufacturer==input$Select1]))
      }) 

      observeEvent(input$Select2,{
        updateSelectizeInput(session,'Select3',
                             choices=unique(Data2$Model_year5[Data2$Manufacturer==input$Select1 & 
                                                                Data2$Model==input$Select2]))
      }) 

      observeEvent(input$Select3,{
        updateSelectizeInput(session,'Select4',
                             choices=unique(Data2$Fuel_type[Data2$Manufacturer==input$Select1 & 
                                                              Data2$Model==input$Select2 & 
                                                              Data2$Model_year5==input$Select3]))

      }) 

      observeEvent(input$Select4,{
        updateSelectInput(session,'Select5',
                          choices=unique(Data2$cost[Data2$Manufacturer==input$Select1 &
                                                             Data2$Model==input$Select2 &
                                                             Data2$Model_year5==input$Select3 &
                                                             Data2$Fuel_type==input$Select4]))
      })

      observeEvent(input$Select6,{
        updateSelectizeInput(session,'Select7',
                             choices=unique(Distances$Destination[Distances$Origin==input$Select6]))
      })

      observeEvent(input$Select7,{
        updateSelectizeInput(session,'Select8',
                             choices=unique(Distances$Distance[Distances$Origin==input$Select6 & 
                                                                 Distances$Destination==input$Select7]))

      })


      output$total1 <- renderText({as.numeric(input$Select8) * as.numeric(input$Select5)}

        )

      }
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
library(shiny)
Data2 <- data.frame(Manufacturer= c(rep("ford", 4)), 
                    Model= c(rep("esport",2), rep("fiesta",2)),
                    Model_year5=c(2018, 2019, 2018, 2019), Fuel_type=c("petrol", "petrol", "diesel", "petrol" ), cost=c(2,4,6,8)
)

Distances <- data.frame(Origin= c("leeds", "London", "Glasgow", "London", "Glasgow"), 
                       Destination = c("Bristol", "Cardiff", "London", "Leeds", "Bristol"),
                       Distance= c(12,13,14,15,16))


ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$style(
            HTML(
                "        #div_id .selectize-control.single .selectize-input:after{
              content: none;
            }"
            ),
            "
                      #container * {  
       display: inline;
                         }")
    ),

    fluidRow(
        column(4, wellPanel(
            selectizeInput("Select1", "Choose Manufacturer", sort(Data2$Manufacturer), 
                           options= list(
                               placeholder = '',
                               onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
            selectizeInput("Select2", "Choose Model", sort(Data2$Model), 
                           options= list(
                               placeholder = '',
                               onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
            selectizeInput("Select3", "Choose Model Year", sort(Data2$Model_year5),
                           options= list(
                               placeholder = '',
                               onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
            selectizeInput("Select4", "Choose Fuel type", sort(Data2$Fuel_type),
                           options= list(
                               placeholder = '',
                               onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
            tags$div(id= "div_id",
                     selectInput("Select5", "£/mile", choices= NULL)),
            selectizeInput("Select6", "Choose Origin", sort(Distances$Origin),
                           options= list(
                               placeholder = '',
                               onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
            selectizeInput("Select7", "Choose Destination", sort(Distances$Distance),
                           options= list(
                               placeholder = '',
                               onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }'))),
            tags$div(id= "div_id",
                     selectInput("Select8", "Distance in Miles", choices= NULL)),
            div(id="container", strong('Total cost of journey: £'), textOutput("total1"))

        ))))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
    output$table = renderTable({
        costtable
    })
    observeEvent(input$Select1,{
        updateSelectizeInput(session,'Select2',
                             choices=unique(Data2$Model[Data2$Manufacturer==input$Select1]))
    }) 

    observeEvent(input$Select2,{
        updateSelectizeInput(session,'Select3',
                             choices=unique(Data2$Model_year5[Data2$Manufacturer==input$Select1 & 
                                                                  Data2$Model==input$Select2]))
    }) 

    observeEvent(input$Select3,{
        updateSelectizeInput(session,'Select4',
                             choices=unique(Data2$Fuel_type[Data2$Manufacturer==input$Select1 & 
                                                                Data2$Model==input$Select2 & 
                                                                Data2$Model_year5==input$Select3]))

    }) 

    observeEvent(input$Select4,{
        updateSelectInput(session,'Select5',
                          choices=unique(Data2$cost[Data2$Manufacturer==input$Select1 &
                                                        Data2$Model==input$Select2 &
                                                        Data2$Model_year5==input$Select3 &
                                                        Data2$Fuel_type==input$Select4]))

        if (input$Select6 != "") {
            updateSelectizeInput(session, 'Select6',
                                 selected = "")
        }
    })

    observeEvent(input$Select6,{
        updateSelectizeInput(session,'Select7',
                             choices=unique(Distances$Destination[Distances$Origin==input$Select6]))
    })

    observeEvent(input$Select7,{
        updateSelectizeInput(session,'Select8',
                             choices=unique(Distances$Distance[Distances$Origin==input$Select6 & 
                                                                   Distances$Destination==input$Select7]))

    })


    output$total1 <- renderText({as.numeric(input$Select8) * as.numeric(input$Select5)}

    )

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I just added this:

```
    if (input$Select6 != "") {
        updateSelectizeInput(session, 'Select6',
                             selected = "")
    }
```

which updates Select6 causing a cascading effect onwards when Select4 is updated.